# What grammatical structure is used here and what does the sentence mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is an excerpt from *The Invisible Man* by H.G. Wells. I can’t understand the italicized part. The excerpt follows:

> His irritability, though it might have been comprehensible to an urban brain-worker, was an amazing thing to these quiet Sussex villagers. The frantic gesticulations they surprised now and then, *the headlong pace after nightfall that swept him upon them round quiet corners,* the inhuman bludgeoning of all tentative advances of curiosity, the taste for twilight that led to the closing of doors, the pulling down of blinds, the extinction of candles and lamps—
>   who could agree with such goings on?

Answer (score 3):

For the grammatical resolution read it from the back:

who could agree with

- frantic gesticulations..
- pace after nightfall ..
- bludgeoning of .. advances ..
- taste for twilight..
- ..

For the semantics: *the headlong pace after nightfall that swept him upon them round quiet corners* means that he paced in the dark and came around quiet corners, head first.

To me the slightly weirder part is the use of *surprise*, which is used not on a person but on 'gesticulations'..

Comment: The online [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surprise) gives the following sub-definition of *surprise:* 2 b :  to detect or elicit by a taking unawares <sometimes surprised a tragic shadow in her eyes — Willa Cather>

Comment: Yes. Maybe 'weird' is a bit too strong, but to my (German) ears it sounded at least unusual.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is a parallel fronting construction. The first occurence is “The frantic gesticulations they suprised now and then”, where you see the object moved forward. The italicized part just omits the predicate “suprised”.

Comment: Could you make it a bit more clear or write the sentence in plain English?

Comment: Plainly speaking, they surprised frantic gesticulations, the headlong pace, the inhuman bludgeoning, etc.